# Tomcat XSS Issue - <script> tag in URL Param

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, xss

In my Tomcat 7.0.88 application, users are able to put a  tag into the URL params, which obviously is a XSS issue. However, I'm not sure how to fix it, and am hoping there's some Tomcat Filter available (either native or 3rd party) or a Java library I can use to solve this issue, instead of attempting to roll my own solution (never a good idea).

The attack can be performed going to a URL in my app like

```
https://<url>/user_report.jsp?round=3</script><script>alert('1');</script>
```

If I put that script tag into a page on Amazon, they sanitize it and remove it.

Also, I'm not even really clear on how this would even trigger the alert to show up, since that tag isn't in the `<HTML>` tag anywhere.

Comment: I should add that this is only an issue on Firefox, since I'm using the Tomcat HttpHeaderSecurityFilter to add the X-XSS-Protection 
1; mode=block header.  Apparently this header is only valid on IE/Edge, Safari, and Chrome

Comment: Nope, it's an issue in your own code: You don't sanitize your inputs. The XSS-Protection header is just bandaid. As mentioned in the comments to the answer: XSS might not be your own validation problem, SQL-injection is another one. The parameter you give might be perfectly valid in other situations - and you may or may not need to sanitize or escape it - based on user permissions, not based on the fact that there's a `<script>` tag contained.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape these characters. For PHP the solution would be simple, for JSP it's a little bit different.

You need to use `<c:out>` tags. Instead of displaying `${round}` on the page, you need to use the escaping tags.

Try using `<c:out value="${round}">` and this will sanitize what is printed on the page by converting HTML special characters to entity values.

Note that you will need to change my solution to suit your application. This should do the trick, but my knowledge of JSP applications is limited.

Comment: By the way, if you are querying a database for the corresponding data to the round number entered, check if it is vulnerable to SQL injection, as that is a very serious issue.

Comment: This is good to know, but I don't think it's my issue.  I never display round directly on the page, and immediately cast the getParameter("round")[0] to an int, so it would throw an exception if that <script> tag was picked up.

Comment: If you're not displaying the content of the GET parameters on the page, then there is really no issue. Any form of user input protocol which is used, should be sanitized depending on where it's stored. Generally speaking you should using techniques like escaping and prepared statements to prevent the aforementioned vulnerabilities. If you don't echo a GET/POST input value on any pages, then you are not vulnerable to XSS (generally speaking).

Comment: The above URL shows the alert window when the page loads in Firefox.  That's what I'm confused about...why would the code execute if I don't embed the URL or any parameter on the page.  That also means it's likely vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: When you visit the page, go to inspect element (or view page source) and check where the code is being displayed. The code has to be included in the DOM for it to be executing like this.

Comment: Yes!  This was a great idea.  I wrote a script that output the source for every page in my application and searched for the </script><script> and flushed out the 2 places where I was, in fact, embedding the parameter on the page.  One was an error page that showed admins the bad parameter being used, which simply <%=%> the bad parameter.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out. And if you do in fact ever need to display the parameter values anywhere, then go ahead and use the secure method I mentioned above.